# What is the best approach to remove from a map when value is greater than x

Tags: java, date, dictionary, concurrency

I am trying to create a `Map<String, Date>` that can hold values until the date value > 1 day old.

Is the best approach to do this to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and then create a thread which iterates the map once every minute or so and then remove the values older than 1 day, or, is there a better approach to doing this?

For clarification the date message received will not be the current time, it can be a time previous

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're creating a timed cache.  May I suggest ehcache?  (Cache eviction is tricky.)

Comment: What do you mean by "date value > 1 day old"?

Comment: the date is more than 1 day ago

Comment: So the values that you will actually be caching are the `String`s and not the `Date`s?

Comment: no i need to store a string -> date (a userid and a date a message was received) - i do not want to keep entrys that have a date which is greater than one day old

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: OK, so I have edited all of the below to use an `Optional<Date>` because Guava's caches don't like the `Callable` or `CacheLoader` to return `null` and you want to use this as a `Map` where the value associated with a key may be absent.

Use Guava's [Cache](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html)

```
Cache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
   .build();
```

Loading Cache would be...

```
   LoadingCache<String, Optional<Date>> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<String, Optional<Date>>() {
         public Optional<Date>load(Stringkey) throws AnyException {
           return Optional.absent();
         }
       });
```

Ok, so I think what you want if the Date may have been in the past is to wrap the above `Cache` in a `ForwardingCache.SimpleForwardingCache`. You then overload the `get` method to return `null` if the Date value is older than a day.

```
Cache<String, Optional<Date>> cache = new SimpleForwardingCache<>(grapsh){

      public Optional<Date>get(String key, Callable<Optional<Date>> valueLoader){
           Optional<Date> result = delegate().get(key, valueLoader);
           if (!result.isPresent() || olderThanADay(result.get()))
                return Optional.absent();
           else
                return result;
      }

      // since you don't really need a valueLoader you might want to add this.
      // this is in place of the LoadingCache, if use LoadingCache use 
      // ForwardingLoadingCache
      public Date get(String key){
          return get(key, 
               new Callable<Optional<Date>>(){
                 public Date call(){return Optional.absent();}
               }
      }
 }
```

Comment: ahhh perfect this looks like exactly what I need, thank you very much - one question however, will this just work on the time of entry or can i specify it to delete based on a field?

Comment: I agree unless `date message was received` is always the current time. OP should clarify if addition solution is needed.

Comment: it will not always be the current time

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment. But I think now it's clear.

Comment: If it is not always the current time, this solution will not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably create a custom class that contains a HashMap, as well as a priority queue of the objects that are also stored in the HashMap. The priority queue is ordered by the system time when the object is too old.

After that, you can have an internal private thread of some kind that sleeps until the next time the first object in the priority queue needs to be removed from the queue and also removed from the HashMap. No need to loop through the HashMap, or check values at a certain rate.

If you don't need to implement it yourself go with a third party library solution like the other answer.

Comment: Not bad (for custom solution instead of using cache), I would just suggest using a DelayQueue instead of a PriortyQueue since it is designed to be time-based.

Answer (score 1):

You can sub-class ConcurrentHashMap, or better yet, wrap the Map and remove any entry it finds which is older than a one day.  This can be done without an additional thread.

Another option is to add the entries to a priority queue and remove from the oldest entries.

Answer (score 1):

I have thought about this in the past, and have derived a few different solutions.  Ultimately, I think that you will want to either implement a Map or extend an existing Map implementation.  Using this implementation should get you what you want, you will need to create a thread that will call the evict method.

```
public class DateKeyedMap<V> extends HashMap<Date, V> {
    public void evictOlderThan (Date dateToDelete) {
       for (Date date : keySet()) {
          if (date.compareTo(dateToDelete) <= 0)  {
             remove(date);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Here is a similar implementation but using the Date as the value, as you are suggesting that you want to map a String to a Date.

```
public class DateValuedMap<K> extends HashMap<K, Date> {
    public void evictOlderThan (Date dateToDelete) {
        for (Date date : values()) {
            if (date.compareTo(dateToDelete) <= 0)  {
                remove(date);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can write your own Map like this:

```
public class DateHashMap implements Map<String, Date>{ 
..
@Override
public String put(Date key, String value) {
        // Check date...
    }
..
}
```

Sincerely,

Max

Comment: The point is to remove from the map 1 day after insert, not prevent insert based on date.